# How to extract information criterions from `lme4::lmer`-model fitted by ML and combine with model summary from REML-fitted model

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models, lmertest

I am trying to access AIC, BIC , logLik and deviance data from a model `summary` of an HLM fitted using maximum likelihood (ML) in `lme4::lmer`, and combine with essentially the same model fitted with restricted maximum likelihood (REML). The structure of the objects returned from `lmer` and `summary` is a mess, and I am unable to find out where/how this data is stored.

**[Update:] Based on the responses I've gotten, I have updated the code to reflect the progress made:**

Code example:

```
# Least working example
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
df <- lme4::sleepstudy
names(df)
# Example model
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ (1|Subject), df, REML = TRUE)
information_criterion <- data.frame(
            "AIC" = AIC(model),
            "BIC" = BIC(model),
            "logLik" = logLik(model),
            "deviance" = deviance(model, REML=FALSE),
            "df.residual" = df.residual(model)
            )
mod_sum <- list(summary(model), information_criterion)
```

###### I essentially want to modify the output to resemble the output of `summary` if `REML = FALSE` (not working):

```
> mod_sum

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: Reaction ~ (1 | Subject)
   Data: df

## Information criterion injected here: ##########################

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid   # <-- THESE ARE THE LINES I WANT
  1916.5   1926.1   -955.3   1910.5      177   # <-- 

##################################################################

REML criterion at convergence: 1904.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4983 -0.5501 -0.1476  0.5123  3.3446 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 1278     35.75   
 Residual             1959     44.26   
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   298.51       9.05  17.00   32.98   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: I think this might be useful? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131272/lme4-why-is-aic-no-longer-displayed-when-using-reml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few points:

1. You have a typo here:

```
    m2sum[["information_criterion"]] <- summary(model1)$information_criterion
```

It should be `m2_sum`

2. Instead of `summary(model1)$information_criterion` you can use:

```
     AIC(model1)
```

So, the following should work:

```
m2_sum[["information_criterion"]] <- AIC(model1)
```

---

Update following change to the OP.

This should work, although please see my last comment, because this may not be a sensible thing to do:

```
> m2_sum$AICtab <- m1_sum$AICtab
> m2_sum

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Reaction ~ (1 | Subject)
   Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1916.5   1926.1   -955.3   1910.5      177 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4983 -0.5501 -0.1476  0.5123  3.3446
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realized I can  add all desired information criterion the same way, without actually fitting an ML-model. I'd be interested in how to add in the output as illustrated though.

Comment: I don't know what you mean *"how to add in the output as illustrated though"* ?

Comment: You have an object  `m2_sum` and you asked how to assign a value to the `information_criterion` slot of that object, and that's what I have answered.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I have updated the model based on your input, and I try show where to display the information. Essentially, I want the output similar to the output of `summary` if `REML = FALSE`.

Comment: OK, I see what you want to do. Please note that this doesn't really make sense because a model fitted with REML does not really have a likelihood to compute AIC with; and this is a good thing because it helps to avoid the big mistake of comparing likelihoods from different models fitted with REML. If you have questions about this I would suggest asking on Cross Validated. I have updated my answer with a possible solution.